# How to adjust the selection 'hotspot' distance?

Tags: selection-tools

Blender's default behavior makes it easy to select a mesh element without the need to hover the mouse cursor exactly over it. Sometimes it's really helpful, sometimes not. I wish I could either adjust that "hotspot" distance between my mouse cursor and the mesh element I want to select or disable it altogether.
Thank you.